# Exception only in Internet Explorer : "The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, exception, csrf, antiforgerytoken

I know there is lots of similar questions about this, but this is different:
This exception happens **ONLY** in *IE*.

Also this is in login page. There is `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` on the form and with or without using this:

```
var addAntiForgeryToken = function (data, form) {
    data.__RequestVerificationToken = $("#" + form + " input[type=hidden]   [name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();
return data;
};
var formdata = addAntiForgeryToken($(this), 'login-form').serialize(),
```

the `__RequestVerificationToken` field is always present in the formdata(in debug mode of IE); but always ajax login function returns this exception. Why?

```
The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException: The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[HttpAntiForgeryException (0x80004005): The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.]
System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.TokenValidator.ValidateTokens(HttpContextBase httpContext, IIdentity identity, AntiForgeryToken sessionToken, AntiForgeryToken fieldToken) +485
System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryWorker.Validate(HttpContextBase httpContext) +71
System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate() +92
System.Web.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) +18
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +97
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<begininvokeaction>
b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +743
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +14
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +343
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<beginexecutecore>
b__1c(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +25
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +465
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<beginexecute>
b__14(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +18
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +20
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +374
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +16
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<beginprocessrequest>
b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +52
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +384
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

**Update:**
My Ajax script code to login:

```
 $(function () {
        configValidations();
        $('#login-form').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#result").html("");
            if ($(this).valid()) {
                var formdata = $('#login-form').serialize();
                wait();
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    cache: false,
                    data: formdata,
                    dataType: "json",                       
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#result').html(ajaxSuccessMessage(""));
                    }
                }).done(function (response) {
                    unwait();
                    if (response.Content == null) {
                        $("#result").html(ajaxErrorMessage(response.Errors[0]));
                    }
                    else {
                        window.location = response.Content
                    }
                }).fail(function (error) {
                    $('#result').html(ajaxValidationBootstrap(error));
                }).always(function () {
                    unwait();
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

The serialized data is present like this:(But it says it is not present)

```
__RequestVerificationToken=BsLh3rc3zlgSna8CDaAN-sK7MsDL4ch0mjk8aW3eKtusSC1MYR4lAEo7HNJz3erAdi2Z3NvrXndFUoFw9FGL5SKTYp_HvFJI-TUg_neb9GQ1&ReturnUrl=&email=demo%40email.com&UserName=demouser&Password=demopasse
```

Comment: Your script makes no sense. If you using `var formdata = $('login-form').serialize();` then the token will be serialized and included in the data (assuming you have included `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` inside the form tags). There is no need to try and add it again.

Comment: Attention I said "with or without using the `code block`  the __RequestVerificationToken field is always present in the formdata" , I mean this is not the problem!

Comment: Using `.serialize()` without your script works fine!

Comment: I found that my problem is how to use ajax function in a way that working in IE too. Because all other fields is not present at the server side too(when I disabled the AntiForgeryToken attribute). So I will add my ajax function to see if there is any problem about it that it is not working in IE.

Comment: I have been tested `.serialize()` with no success!

Comment: So have I (with all browsers) and it works fine. If its not working for you then its due to code you have not shown.

Comment: Start by removing `processData :false,`

Comment: No change with removing `processData :false,`

Comment: It has to be removed. And you cannot use `$(this).serialize(),` - it needs to be `$('form').serialize()` (`this` is not your form). And what is `wait()`? But since your ultimately wanting to redirect, using ajax is pointless - you should be just making a normal submit.

Comment: `this` is my form object in the form submit function (using form id did not change result). `wait()` is a function that shows a loading image on top of all page. What is the problem with redirect with ajax? Do you mean that login with ajax is pointless?

Comment: You just keep changing your code every time I point out an error. I give up.